# Issue creating independent grids from the same object with SlickGrid

Tags: javascript, object, slickgrid

I am having issues creating multiple independent `SlickGrid` grids from the same object (that is modifications to one grid shouldn't affect the other grids and vice versa).

Here is the code

```
var data1 = [];
data1[0] = { myfield: "This is data1" };
// setting data2, see below
var grid1 = new Slick.Grid("#grid1", data1, columns, options);
var grid2 = new Slick.Grid("#grid2", data2, columns, options);
```

**Setting data2**

I've tried many things:
-`var data2 = data1`: when doing so, whenever I modify one grid, the other grid gets updated accordingly and vice versa, which I understand is [because of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript).

-`var data2 = jQuery.extend(true, {}, data1)` or `var data2 = jQuery.extend({}, data1);`: in this case `SlickGrid` simply fails to create the grid for `data2` (the grid is empty and its height extends for `4000000px`, no warnings/errors/exceptions are thrown) although the object itself seems to be properly created (I can alert it and the its values are good).

**How can I create 2 independent grids from the same object (initially) with `SlickGrid`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery.extend() works on an object.  Here, you have to create a second array and clone every individual item from the first array separately.